# How to break up string response?

Tags: android, json, rest

I am receiving a String response from the following @Override method

```
@Override
publc void onSuccess(String response) {
....
}
```

The conflict I am facing is that I do not know how to break up this response into key value pairings. This is an example of the response.

{"action":{"generic_message":"test generic message"},"domains":{"key_example_one":"https:/google.com","api_root_url":"https://test.com/new/0.2/json"},"page":null}}

I have attempted to convert the string to a JSONObject, and then adding the JSONObjects to a JSONArray.

```
JSONObject mJObj;
try {
    mJObj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray mJArry = mJObj.getJSONArray("action");

    for (int i = 0; i < mJArry.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject newObj = mJArry.getJSONObject(i);    
        String test2 = newObj.getString("generic_example_for_all_platforms");

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT: I am getting JSON exception that JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject, for the following line.

```
JSONArray mJArry = mJObj.getJSONArray("action");
```

Thanks in advante

Comment: the org.json library is not the most pleasant to work with; I'd recommend looking into gson or jackson

Comment: Yea, I usually use loopj actually, but this is job requirement. I only have to work with what they already have.

Comment: Ah, that sucks. When I run the above code I get the error 'org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["action"] is not a JSONArray.' are you sure that the description of the error in your question/the json string is correct?

Comment: Yea, I posted the response directly. generic_message is the key and the value is test generic message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do want to read more about JSON [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/).

The first thing to know is that {} is equal to a Json Object and [] is equal to a Json Array.

```
try {
    JSONObject mJObj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject actionJsonObject = mJObj.getJSONObject("action");
    String generic_message = actionJsonObject.getString("generic_message");
    JSONObject domainsJsonObject = mJObj.getJSONObject("domains");
    String key_example_one = domainsJsonObject.getString("key_example_one");
    String api_root_url = domainsJsonObject.getString("api_root_url");
    String page = mJObj.getString("page");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
```

EDIT: 

Just saw that you can't move to other Json processors. The property 'action' holds a JSONObject not a JSONArray. What about 
`JSONObject jsonObject = mJObj.getJSONObject("action")`.